# Get notified if an element has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

is there any chance to trigger an event whenever an element changed by WHATEVER? The reason could be the user entered something, of course this gets triggered. But I would also need to react on the situation when f. e. an other ajax-script leads to a change of an element, ad DIV or SPAN for example.

The Change-Event is not triggered in this situation, so any hint how to get this solved?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: MutationObserver wasn't supported until ie11, doesn't seem realistic at this point in time

Answer (score 0):

> is there any chance to trigger an event whenever an element changed by WHATEVER?

Yes, on modern browsers you can use mutation observers ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#mutation-observers) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)). Some older browsers may support the older, now-deprecated mutation events. There are even a couple of bridging projects [like this one](https://github.com/polymer/MutationObservers) that implement mutation observers on older browsers using mutation events, so for instance you could use one of those to get mutation observers back in IE9 (which partially supported mutation events).

Barring a browser supporting mutation observers or mutation events, sadly, your only option is polling (blech).